# Cadastrar vários elementos com várias imagens associadas num BD de uma vez só no php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo uma função para se cadastrar produtos numa plataforma de E-Commerce.

A função é a seguinte: o usuário cadastra o produto base depois cadastra as variações dele(cor e tamanho, por exemplo). Se o produto base não tiver variações, ainda assim será adicionado no tabela de variações, por comodidade.

Para cadastrar os produto variação, o usuário seleciona 1 ou duas variações, depois coloca o preço e a quantidade de cada um deles e logo depois seleciona as imagens referente a cada variação primária.

Ex: Cadastro de um tênis da cor vermelha, tamanhos 38, 39 e 40. O usuário seleciona um número X de imagens referente a esse tênis, que possui variação primária "cor vemelha", ou seja, essas imagens serão exibidas pra todos os tamanhos desse tênis, o que importa na seleção das imagens é a variação primária.

O meu problema começa aqui. Como ligar as imagens a cada produto correspondente, sendo que o número de imagens é variável? Para adicionar as outras informações (preço e quantidade) eu criei um array de inputs, mas não acho que com as imagens possa ser feito assim, devido a essa não limitação no número que podem ser selecionados.

E todos esse produtos devem ser inseridos de uma vez só no BD, juntamente com as suas imagens.

Parte do código atual(os produtos são criados dinamicamente no php):

Div com os inputs de informação do produto:

```
echo "                  <div class='small-9 columns'>";
echo "                    <input type='hidden' name='opVar1ProdutoPV[]' value='$opcao1'>";
echo "                    <input type='hidden' name='opVar2ProdutoPV[]' value='0'>";
echo "                    <div class='row'>";
echo "                      <div style='padding-top:1%' class='small-4 columns'>";
echo "                        <input name='precoReal[]' type='text' id='preco' placeholder='Preco:'>";
echo "                      </div>";
echo "                      <div style='padding-top:1%' class='small-4 columns'>";
echo "                        <input name='quantidade[]' type='text' id='qtd' placeholder='Quantidade'>";
echo "                      </div>";
echo "                      <div style='padding-top:1%' class='small-4 columns'>";
echo "                        <a id='remover$opcao1' class='button tiny small remover'>Excluir</a>";
echo "                      </div>";
echo "                    </div>";
echo "                  </div>";
```

Div de cadastro das imagens:

```
echo "              <div style='float:left' class='small-12 columns'>";
echo "                <ul id='adicionarImagensPV$opcao1'>";
echo "                   <li style='width:20%;display:inline-block'>";
echo "                      <input id='imagemPV$opcao1' type='file' name='imagensPV[]' class='imagensPV'>";
echo "                      <input id='imagemPV$opcao1' type='hidden' name='imagensPV[]' class='imagensPV'>";
echo "                   </li>";
echo "                </ul>";
echo "              </div>";
```

Estrturas simplificadas das tabelas:

Produto

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produtovariacao` (
`idProdutoVariacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idProdutoBase` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idOpcaoVariacao1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idOpcaoVariacao2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantidade` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precoReal` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `produtoimagem` (
`idProdutoImagem` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idProdutoVariacao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linkProdutoImagem` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
)

As FK foram todas declaradas.

Comment: Pose é código que você já tem. Você terá de usar outra tabela `N - M`. Exemplo: tabela->`imgs_produtos`, colunas -> `id`,`idproduto`,`imagem`, assim basta associar `idproduto` com o id do produto na sua tabela de produtos. Ao fazer `INSERT` de uma nova imagem será apenas colocar um registro na tabela `imgs_produtos` com o id do produto e o caminho da imagem.

Comment: Já estou usando duas tabelas, estou com dificuldade em associar as imagens nos produtos correspondentes para salvar na tabela.

Comment: Poste a estrutura das suas tabelas.